# How to find a list of lists of all possible paths in a tree

Tags: python, list, recursion

I need to find a list of lists when traversing through a list of objects in python and need to create every possible path

The output should look something like this

```
[[24,137,237], [24,137,251], [24,151,155], [24,151,155,154]]
```

The input looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 24,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 137,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 237,
                        "children": [],
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 251,
                        "children": [],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": 151,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 155,
                        "children": [],
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 154,
                        "children": [],
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Current code does something similar but not quite the desired result.

```py
def create_category_paths_from_children(
        children: List[CategoriesTreeNodeFull], category_paths_list: List[CategoryPath]
    ) -> List[CategoryPath]:

    for child in children:
        category_paths_list.append(CategoryPath(name=child.name, id=child.id))
        if len(child.children) > 0:
            create_category_paths_from_children(child.children, category_paths_list)
    
    return category_paths_list
```

**Edit:** Updated my current code.

Comment: how is this data structure stored? in a python class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the recursive approach, the principle is to keep executing update_path until no children exist, when the condition is met, directly call the global variables to append the list elements, otherwise keep recursively executing down and update ancestors, ancestors、 children、 id represent all parent id list, children list, the current level id value：

```
items = [
    {
        "id": 24,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 137,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 237,
                        "children": [],
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 251,
                        "children": [],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "id": 151,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 155,
                        "children": [],
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 154,
                        "children": [],
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
]


class Node:
    def __init__(self, nid, ancestors, children):
        self.ancestors = ancestors
        self.children = children
        self.id = nid

    def update_path(self):
        if not self.children:
            global res
            res.append(self.ancestors + [self.id])
        else:
            for _item in self.children:
                node = Node(_item["id"], self.ancestors + [self.id], _item.get("children", []))
                node.update_path()

res = []
for item in items:
    Node(item["id"], [], item["children"]).update_path()

print(res)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[24, 137, 237], [24, 137, 251], [24, 151, 155], [24, 151, 154]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```py
def getAllPaths(tree, upto = [], current_trees = []):
    upto = upto + [tree.id]
    if len(tree.children) == 0:
        current_trees.append(upto)
    else:
        for branch in tree.children:
            getAllPaths(branch, upto, current_trees)
    return current_trees
```

This is assuming the "object" you described looks something like the following in python code:

```py
class Tree:
    id = 0           # Some int
    children = []    # Some list of Tree objects
```